# please suggest a hosted survey tool with an API

Tags: c#, asp.net, survey

I'm tasked with implementing a survey addition to an existing website. We have been doing this survey with SurveyMonkey, which seems excellent, but the client doesn't like that it isn't on their site. SurveyMonkey doesn't have an API that I can plug into.

I've investigated Survey(tm) on http://survey.codeplex.com/. Terrible name:

```
What survey tool are you using? 
Oh, Survey. 
Yes, what survey tool are you using?
I said Survey. 
Ugh, so did I but which one?!
```

Spent about an hour trying to get the sample site running on my machine and decided to move on.

**What are my other options**? Ideally I'd like to administer the Survey on a remote site (like SurveyMonkey) and pull questions/push answers from my site to their database. I'm also open to the idea of doing this entirely in house but don't want to build something from the ground up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would look at [SurveyGizmo](http://www.surveygizmo.com/). You should be able to deal with their [API](http://developer.surveygizmo.com/) and handle everything remotely.

Comment: Do you have experience with it?

Comment: I haven't used SurveyGizmo's API, but SurveyGizmo's question editor was quite powerful. See my review at http://wiki.dandascalescu.com/reviews/online_services/online_survey_sites

Comment: SurveyGizmo's API is quite good except responses can take between 45 seconds and 10 minutes to appear in the results depending on time of day.

Comment: @whitehawk agreed. Very happy with SG so far, but this delay is probably the biggest pain point-- we have to build abstractions of their API to give our users real-time feedback on survey submissions. Their API is also rate-limited.

Answer (score 2):

You can try LimeSurvey (http://www.limesurvey.org/) which comes with extensive API: http://manual.limesurvey.org/wiki/RemoteControl_2_API.

Usually you would install it on your own server, but hosted versions are available as well:

- http://www.limesurvey.com/hosting
- http://www.limeservice.com/en/

Comment: Yep : API doc : https://manual.limesurvey.org/RemoteControl_2_API . But easy install on a LAMP/WAMP

Answer (score 1):

I would use Examinare.

The API is so easy to implement. Just check this out: 5 lines of code :)

https://developer.examinare.com/apidocs/addrecipient/

And they have some tutorials in there under "How to start".